# Can a Binomial Distribution be standardized to a Standard Normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Can a Binomial Distribution be standardized to a Standard Normal distribution? Using Central Limit Theorem..

Comment: What do you mean by "standardized"?

Comment: what do you mean by `standardized`?

Comment: I mean that Z~N(0,1)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @Lovsovs ok, forget the part of standardization. How could I transform a Binomial Distribution into a Normal Distribution using Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Let $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Ian thanks for your help. $\mu$ is $np$ and $\sigma$ is $sqrt(np(1-p))$ for Binomial distribution. So, when we use Central Limit Theorem, doesn't the expected value of the summation of $X_i$ is $n\mu$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Any normal distribution can be transformed to the standard normal distribution by means of the mapping $ z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$. We know that a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ (representing number of trials and success probability, respectively) can be approximated by a normal distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$. Applying the standardization above gives a standard normal distribution.

As Kenny Wong states, I should add that $n$ should be "large enough" in order for the approximation to be good. He claims $n$ needs to be at least $10$, while I found that in many texts, $n \geq 30$ is usually the way to go. I don't think this magic number is uniform, but the idea is to make sure you have enough sample points.

Comment: I forgot about that! See the updated answer.

Comment: yes. My question is that I got on my notebook that Central Limit Theorem has this property: $\Sigma X_i ~ N(n\mu,\sigma \sqrt n)$, so the mean of my approximated variable is $n p$ or $n \mu = n^2 p$ ?

Comment: There is no "magic number" - it all depends on how you quantify the approximation to be "good enough". (I know many textbooks provide such random numbers, and I think that is just aimed at students who are not pursuing a career in a mathematical field, to give them some sense of what "sufficiently large" could mean.)

Comment: By the way, $ \widehat p = \overline x$ is an unbiased estimator? I think the most likelihood estimator to p is $ \widehat p=\frac{\overline x}{n}$, but what shall I use?